# What might this animal be?

Tags: species-identification

I have found two species of this strange looking animal on the Eastern shore of the Adriatic Sea and I was simply unable to recognise them.
[image]

Comment: This is probably a gastropod mollusc without (secondarily) shell, a sea slug (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_slug).

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an [Aplysia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aplysia), or "sea hare", a marine gastropod. Some of them sometimes get stranded and look like fat violet/green/brown blobs, around 10cm diameter. In the water, they swim slowly. I've seen some in Brittany (France) and in Algarve (Portugal).

Answer (score 2):

As bli said it is Aplysia more specifically *[Aplysia fasciata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aplysia_fasciata)* ,commonly called Sooty sea hare.

It is an Atlantic species of gastropod mollusc of the family Aplysiidae.

> This sea hare occurs in the Western Atlantic from New Jersey to Brazil, and in the Eastern Atlantic including the Mediterranean and the West African coast.

**Picture references:**

[image]

From: [ipaq](http://www.ipaq.org.br)

[image]
From: [gbif.org](http://www.gbif.org/species/5191263)